# Can Sitecore (ContentSearch) SeachMaxResults for Solr be redefined at runtime?

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, sitecore8

Currently I am using the default configuration value of:

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults" value="500" />
```

I need, for a specific Solr (ContentSearch) query, to return all items of a specific *Template ID*.  The total returned will be in excess of 1200 items.

I tried using the paging feature to override *SearchMaxResults* by invoking a query as follows:

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Filter(i => i["_template"].Equals(variantTemplateId));
query = query.Page(1, 1500);
var results = query.GetResults();
```

However, I still only receive a single page of 500 items as the 1500 Page Size won't override the *SearchMaxResults* value of 500.

I really don't want to increase *SearchMaxResults* for all queries as it's going to have a negative impact overall on search.  It would be ideal if I could set this parameter to "" (unlimited results) temporarily, run my query, and reset it back to default - but I don't see a way to be able to do this.  I also cannot use `GetDescendants()` as a mean of acquiring all these items as it negatively impacts site performance, even if I only do it one time and store my results in Memory Cache.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it's good to keep the `SearchMaxResults` to a reosanble low number, such as 500. When you know you might need to fetch more data, you can perform several queries in a loop, for example like this:

```
int skip = 0;
const int chunkSize = 500;
bool fetchMore = true;
while (fetchMore) {
  var q = context.GetQueryable<MyModel>()
       .Filter(....)
       ...
       .Skip(skip).Take(chunkSize)
       .Select (d => new { d.field1, d.field2, ... })
       .GetResults();
  var cnt = 0;
  foreach (var doc in q.Hits) {
    // do stuff
    cnt ++;
  }
  skip += cnt;
  fetchMore = cnt == chunkSize;
}
```

As slightly noted above, I've used the `Select` method to limit the number of fields returned. This will specify the `fl` Solr field to return just the fields you need. Otherwise `fl=*,score` will be used and cause a lot of data to be sent over the network and deserializing it can be quite heavy. (I have a separate post on this here: https://mikael.com/2019/01/optimize-sitecore-solr-queries/)

Comment: Thanks for this!  The contentsearch returns are so quick, all the weight of the processing remains in the processing of the returned data, which is what I wanted.